# Android studio: Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD ____ has terminated

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

When I try to open a wearos AVD, there is always such an error. It only appears when I turn on wearos AVD, and everything is normal when I turn on mobile AVD. I have searched a lot on the Internet, which is useless. Here are the methods I have tried for these things:
1.uninstall and reinstall the emulator;
2.uninstall and reinstall Android Studio;
3.create the AVD with diffrent images;
4.restart my computer;
The app is fine because I have tested it on my Physical device. \ 
My computer:macOS 12.2, 154.62GB used(total 1T), Apple Silicon M1Pro(10cpu cores and 16 gpu cores) 16Gb ram.
Thanks in advance.\
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyNMg.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after looking for information on the web, i finally figure this out.
The reason is: I am using a M1pro Macbook, and google haven't got any arm64-v8a WearOS Image. But they got arm64-v8a android image, so android is fine.
Hope this will give you some help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the .android (click cmd + shift +. to reveal hidden files)folder and delete the emulator folder. Now open android studio and all your AVD s will be gone.. Do a invalidate cache and restart just in case and create a fresh AVD

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer but it doesn't work. Do you have got a better method?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Android studio device manager, then cold boot the AVD, then you can run the AVD

Comment: Doesn't work, same error message.